# gnuplot - formatting the title of a plot (bar over letter)

Tags: formatting, gnuplot

I want to produce a gnuplot which contains a **bar over a letter** in the title of a plot. The image shows such an attempt:

[image]

The code producing it, is as follows (i paste these line into the **gnuplot-window in Windows 7**):

```
set terminal pdf enhanced
set output "C:/linMitSaett.pdf"
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#D3D3D3"
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#D3D3D3"
set yrange [0:800]
set xlabel "Zeiteinheit {/Symbol t}" 
set ylabel "#Individuen  p({/Symbol t})"
set label "p_0=2" textcolor rgb "red" at 4,300
set label "p_0=400" textcolor rgb "blue" at 1,425
set label "p_0=800" textcolor rgb "green" at 4,510
set label "{/Symbol l}_0=200 (Wachstumsrate)\n{/Symbol l}_1=0.5 (Bremsrate)" at 4,160
plot [0:10] 400+(2-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 < ~p{.7-}", 400+(800-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 > ~p{.7-}", 400+(400-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 = ~p{.7-}"
set output "C:/deleteme.pdf"
reset
```

**How can i move the lines vertically downwards, so that they are aligned with each p and not with the bar over each p?**

Comment: I have to edit the post, i am working on it, got problems with gnuplot.

Answer (score 8):

If you add `set encoding utf8` to your file, you can simply use the overline character (U+203E) in the labels.  This removes the need to add an offset to the character:

```
plot [0:10] 400+(2-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 < ~p‾", \
            400+(800-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 > ~p‾", \
            400+(400-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 = ~p‾"
```

If entering the overline symbol is impossible in your editor, you can also use the octal code for the UTF-8 character:

```
plot [0:10] 400+(2-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 < ~p\342\200\276", \
            400+(800-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 > ~p\342\200\276", \
            400+(400-400)*exp(-0.5*x) title "p_0 = ~p\342\200\276"
```